# How do I implement a join with a between in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a Hive table with the numeric version of an IP address. I have another table with start, end, location where start and end define a range of numeric IPs associated with a location.

```
Example
Numeric: 29

start | end | location
----------------------
1     | 11  | 666
12    | 30  | 777
31    | 40  | 888

Output: 29 - 777
```

I need to use the IP from table 1 to lookup the location from table 2. I'm new to Hive and have discovered that I can't use BETWEEN or < > in join statements. I've been trying to figure out some way of making this happen using Hive SQL and can't figure it out. Is there a way? I'm somewhat familiar with UDFs as well if one of those is needed. I'm open to the idea that this isn't possible in Hive and I need to do with Pig or a Java Map/Reduce job, I just don't know enough about things at this point to say.

Any help is appreciated. **Thanks.**

Answer (score 2):

Hive and Pig do not support such inequality join. You can use cross join and where to do it. But it's inefficient. A simple example:

```
SELECT t1.ip, t2.location_ip FROM t1 JOIN t2
WHERE t1.ip >= t2.start_ip and t1.ip<=t2.start_ip ;
```

However, it seems you want to do cross join a big table and a small table. If so, maybe the following statement is more efficient:

```
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(t2) */ t1.ip, t2.location_ip FROM t1 JOIN t2
WHERE t1.ip >= t2.start_ip and t1.ip<=t2.start_ip ;
```